# LaserScan scan_time for multiple scans in a single rotation

Tags: lidar, message

I have a LiDAR device that reports the entire 360 degree range, but split into scans of 22.5 degrees each, and I'm trying to assemble my LaserScan messages correctly.

As I understand, each 22.5 scan (17 measurements) will have its own message, but my confusion is regarding `scan_time`, which is defined as `time between scans`.

From [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/86988/explanation-on-sensor-msgs-laserscan-and-time):

> Think of scan time as the time taken for a full rotation of the sensor even if it's only producing data for part of that revolution.

Which makes sense for that particular question, because their sensor is only reporting a single range of angles, but mine reports a full rotation, albeit in multiple scans. Does the same "full rotation" argument works for my case? Or the time between scans in my case is the time for a single 22.5 scan?

Also this question [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/57509/laserscanscan-time-doubt) tells me that I should use the time for a single 22.5 scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the comment in `LaserScan.msg` to mean it is the interval, in float seconds, from the start-of-LaserScan-msg-N to start-of-LaserScan-msg-(N+1).

That said, I don't think this field is very critical, and I suspect you could probably set it to 0.0 without a problem.

For what it is worth, I've never seen a ros driver output distinct LaserScan messages with 22.5 degree arcs like you describe. It's far more typical for the ros driver to assemble a single message with 360-degrees of data in it.